# How can I know if a TIFF image is in the format CCITT T.6(Group 4)?

Tags: image, format, tiff, identification

How can I know if a TIFF image is in the format CCITT T.6(Group 4)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this (C#) code example.
It returns a value indicating the compression type:

1: no compression
2: CCITT Group 3
3: Facsimile-compatible CCITT Group 3 
4: CCITT Group 4 (T.6)
5: LZW

```
public static int GetCompressionType(Image image)
{
    int compressionTagIndex = Array.IndexOf(image.PropertyIdList, 0x103);
    PropertyItem compressionTag = image.PropertyItems[compressionTagIndex];
    return BitConverter.ToInt16(compressionTag.Value, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check these links

- [The TIFF File Format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/corion.htm)
- [TIFF Tag Compression](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html)
- [TIFF File Format Summary](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm)

The tag 259 (hex 0x0103) store the info about the Compression method.

--- Compression
Tag  = 259  (103)
Type = word
N    = 1
Default = 1.

1 =  No compression, but pack data into bytes as tightly as possible, with no
     unused  bits except  at the end of a row. The bytes are stored as an array
     of bytes, for BitsPerSample <= 8,  word if BitsPerSample > 8 and <= 16, and
     dword if BitsPerSample > 16 and <= 32. The byte ordering of data >8 bits
     must be consistent with that specified in the TIFF file header (bytes 0
     and 1). Rows are required to  begin on byte boundaries.

2 =  CCITT Group 3 1-Dimensional Modified Huffman run length encoding.
     See ALGRTHMS.txt BitsPerSample must be 1, since this type of compression
     is defined only for bilevel images (like FAX images...)

3 =  Facsimile-compatible CCITT  Group 3, exactly as specified in
     "Standardization of  Group 3  facsimile  apparatus  for  document
     transmission,"   Recommendation T.4,  Volume VII, Fascicle VII.3,
     Terminal Equipment  and Protocols  for  Telematic  Services,  The
     International  Telegraph  and  Telephone  Consultative  Committee
     (CCITT), Geneva,  1985, pages  16 through  31.   Each strip  must
     begin on  a byte  boundary.   (But recall  that an image can be a
     single strip.)   Rows  that are  not the first row of a strip are
     not required  to begin on a byte boundary.  The data is stored as
     bytes,  not words - byte-reversal  is   not  allowed.    See  the
     Group3Options field for Group 3 options such as 1D vs 2D coding.

**4 =  Facsimile-compatible CCITT  Group 4**, exactly as specified in
     "Facsimile Coding  Schemes and Coding Control Functions for Group
     4 Facsimile Apparatus,"  Recommendation T.6, Volume VII, Fascicle
     VII.3, Terminal  Equipment and  Protocols for Telematic Services,
     The International  Telegraph and Telephone Consultative Committee
     (CCITT), Geneva,  1985, pages  40 through  48.   Each strip  must
     begin on  a byte  boundary.  Rows that are not the first row of a
     strip are  not required to begin on a byte boundary.  The data is
     stored as  bytes, not  words.   See the  Group4Options field  for
     Group 4 options.

5 =  LZW Compression, for grayscale, mapped color, and full color images.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `identify -verbose` from the [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) suite on the image. Look for "Compression: Group4" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

SO, I downloaded the `libtiff` library from the link I mentioned before, and from what I've seen, you can do the following: (untested)

```
int isTIFF_T6(const char* filename)
{
TIFF* tif= TIFFOpen(filename,"r");
TIFFDirectory *td = &tif->tif_dir;
if(td->td_compression == COMPRESSION_CCITTFAX4) return 1;
return 0;
}
```

**PREVIOUS:**
[This page](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-16.html) has a lot of information about this format and links to some code in C:

Here's an excerpt:

> The following paper covers T.4, T.6
>   and JBIG:
>
> "Review of standards for electronic
>   imaging for facsimile systems" in
>   Journal of Electronic Imaging, Vol. 1,
>   No. 1, pp. 5-21, January 1992.
>
> Source code can be obtained as part of
>   a TIFF toolkit - TIFF image
>   compression techniques for binary
>   images include CCITT T.4 and T.6:
>
> ftp://ftp.sgi.com/graphics/tiff/tiff-v3.4beta035-tar.gz
>   Contact: sam@engr.sgi.com
>
> Read more: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/compression-faq/part1/section-16.html#ixzz0TYLGKnHI