# How to read TIFF compression property? Can i Use System.Windows.Media.Imaging?

Tags: tiff

I'm trying to find ways to get the Compression property from TIFF images. I found a method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548446/how-can-i-know-if-a-tiff-image-is-in-the-format-ccitt-t-6group-4) that works, but I'm wondering if i can use the  System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace to do this?

Looking at [TiffBitmapEncoder.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapencoder.compression.aspx) it says:
"Gets or sets a value that indicates the type of compression that is used by this Tagged Image File Format (TIFF) image."

I'm not sure if i'm interpreting this correctly, but how would one GET the value?

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548446/how-can-i-know-if-a-tiff-image-is-in-the-format-ccitt-t-6group-4